# PINE Script - plotshape works but order execute randomly works with the same Variable

Tags: pine-script

I am into my 1st Pine script...Managed to plotshape with variable 'validEntry' just to see if they are valid. But when I want to execute a 'strategy.entry' it does on some 'validEntry' but misses some.

```
`//ONLY ENTERS POSITIONS ON SOME VALID ENTRIES HERE
if validEntry and isBull
    stopPrice := low - extraPips
    pips := close - stopPrice
    stopPrice := low - pips*xtSL
    limitPrice := close + (pips*xtTG)
    // strategy.entry(id="HS_bl", long=true)
    strategy.entry(id="HS_bl", long=true, stop=stopPrice,limit=limitPrice)

//WORKS WELL HERE PLOTTING ALL
plotshape(series=validEntry, style=shape.labeldown,color = color.new(color.green, transp = 80))`
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's either because you're using limit or stop orders.

Comment: Yes I am....I found the issue today..it had to do with PYRAMIDING which was set to zero in my code...it only allowed one SHORT until a LONG was placed...then only one LONG until the next short was placed